# How to do an image-slider with autoplay ? Using Javascript and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slide, autoplay

I've been trying to figure out how to autoplay the images that I configured in the manual form and I'd like the autoplay works at the same way as the manual. Is it possible? I tried so many times ):
I can not understand why my text, bullets (dots) and images doesn't work automatically and properly.

Anyone ?

I will let the codepen here too, cause the code and design is to extensive
[[https://codepen.io/thyaladias/pen/KKowVPo]](https://codepen.io/thyaladias/pen/KKowVPo)

here is part of my HTML

```
<div class="carousel">
              <div class="images-wrapper">
                <img src="images/1.abstract.png" class="image img-1 show" alt="">
                <img src="images/2.abstract.png" class="image img-2" alt="">
                <img src="images/3.abstract.png" class="image img-3" alt="">
              </div>

              <div class="texto-slider">
                <div class="text-wrap">
                  <div class="container-texto">
                    <h2>Create your own courses</h2>
                    <h2>Customize as you like</h2>
                    <h2>Invite students to your class</h2>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="bullets">
                  <span class="active" data-value="1"></span>
                  <span data-value="2"></span>
                  <span data-value="3"></span>
                </div>
              </div>
     </div>
```

the css :

```
.carousel {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 55%;
  left: 45%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #f5e4d9;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

.images-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.images-wrapper h2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  max-height: 2.2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}


.image {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 30px;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.5s;
}

.img-1
{
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: translate(0, -50px);
}

.img-2 {
  transform: scale(0.4, 0.5);
}

.img-3 {
  transform: scale(0.3) rotate(-20deg);
}

.image.show {
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: none;
}

.texto-slider {
  margin-top: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

}

.text-wrap {
  max-height: 2.2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.container-texto {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.container-texto h2 {
  line-height: 2.2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.bullets {
  display: inline-block;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bullets span {
  width: 0.5rem;
  height: 0.5rem;
  background-color: #aaa;
  margin: 0 0.25rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  display: inline-block;
}

.bullets span.active {
  width: 1.1rem;
  background-color: #151111;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  z-index: 5;
  transition: 0.3s
}
```

and JS:

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".campo-input"); 
const toggle_btn = document.querySelectorAll(".toggle"); 
const main = document.querySelector("main");
const bullets = document.querySelectorAll(".bullets span");
const images = document.querySelectorAll(".image");

inputs.forEach((inp) => {
  inp.addEventListener("focus", () => {
    inp.classList.add("active");
  });
  inp.addEventListener("blur", () => {
    if (inp.value != "") return;
    inp.classList.remove("active");
  });
});

toggle_btn.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    main.classList.toggle("sign-up-mode");
  });
});


function moveSlider() {
  let index = this.dataset.value;

  let currentImage = document.querySelector(`.img-${index}`);
  images.forEach((img) => img.classList.remove("show"));
  currentImage.classList.add("show");

  const textSlider = document.querySelector(".container-texto");
  textSlider.style.transform = `translateY(${-(index - 1) * 2.2}rem)`;

  bullets.forEach((bull) => bull.classList.remove("active"));
  this.classList.add("active");
}

bullets.forEach((bullet) => {
  bullet.addEventListener("click", moveSlider);
});


$(document).ready(function () { 
  $('.carousel > img:gt(0)').hide();

  setInterval(() => {
      $('.carousel > img:first')
          .fadeOut(1000) 
          .next() 
          .fadeIn(1000) 
          .end()
          .appendTo('.carousel') 
  }, 3000);  

})
```

Comment: I think you want to do the interval and call `moveSlider()` every time. This what happens when you click the bullets anyway

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, but you didn't have jquery support added, and  it is telling me you have a syntax error that `dataset` is undefined.